# Qual formato de cor deve ser usado nos parâmetros de range da função "cv2.inRange"?

Tags: opencv, cores, range

Eu quero criar uma máscara para a minha imagem com o OpenCV usando a função `inRange`, porém não sei qual o formato de cor utilizar. Na documentação só diz que a imagem (primeiro parâmetro) deve estar em HSV, porém não fala o formato das cores do *range*.

Eu encontrei um exemplo do uso dele [nesse](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multiple-color-detection-in-real-time-using-python-opencv/) site, que define o seguinte *range* para a cor azul:

```
blue_lower = np.array([94, 80, 2], np.uint8)
blue_upper = np.array([120, 255, 255], np.uint8)
blue_mask = cv2.inRange(hsvFrame, blue_lower, blue_upper)
```

O problema é que se o formato da cor for RBG, o `blue_lower` tem cor amarela e o `blue_upper` tem cor azul. Se o formato da cor for BGR, dá no mesmo só que fica invertido. E o formato certamente não deve ser HSV porque os dois últimos valores são maiores que `100%`.

Disso isso, qual formato de cor eu devo usar? Se for mesmo BGR ou RGB, esse *range* para a cor azul está realmente correto?

Comment: Não manjo de OpenCV e muito menos de C++ mas no repositório do projeto tem [este teste](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/68d15fc62edad980f1ffa15ee478438335f39cc3/modules/python/test/test_copytomask.py#L25) que usa BGR e [esse aqui](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/68d15fc62edad980f1ffa15ee478438335f39cc3/samples/cpp/tutorial_code/video/meanshift/camshift.cpp#L51) também.. então suponho que dê pra assumir que o formato de cores é esse mesmo.

Comment: Estas duas respostas falam sobre isso: > Diferentes aplicações usam diferentes escalas para o HSV. Por exemplo gimp usa H = 0-360, S = 0-100 and V = 0-100. Mas OpenCV usa H: 0-179, S: 0-255, V: 0-255. 1- [Choosing the correct upper and lower HSV boundaries for color detection with `inRange` (OpenCV)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948589/choosing-the-correct-upper-and-lower-hsv-boundaries-for-color-detection-withcv/48367205#answers) 2- [How to detect two different colors using `cv2.inRange` in Python-OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48109650/how-to-detect-two-different-color

Comment: @LucasPedro obrigado pela a sua ajuda!

Comment: Pessoal, vocês podem por favor me explicar o motivo de tantos negativos, tanto na pergunta quanto na resposta?

Comment: Jean, eu também não entendo o que acontece com o Stack em português. Então te dei um upvote pra dar uma moral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `cv2.inRange()` usa HSV (que já deve saber, é usado por ser mais próximo ao que os olhos humanos percebem) e se buscar **na própria documentação**:

- https://docs.opencv.org/master/df/d9d/tutorial_py_colorspaces.html

Já teria a a explicação dos intervalos que a API usa:

> For HSV, hue range is [0,179], saturation range is [0,255], and value range is [0,255]. Different software use different scales. So if you are comparing OpenCV values with them, you need to normalize these ranges.

Traduzindo:

> Para HSV, o intervalo de **matiz (hue/H) é [0,179]**, o intervalo de **saturação (saturation/h) é [0,255]** e o intervalo de **valor (value/V) é [0,255]**. Softwares diferentes usam escalas diferentes, então se você está comparando valores do OpenCV com eles, você precisará normalizar esses intervalos.

No entanto isso você vai usar se deseja fazer na "mão" (claro que depende do que você deseja fazer), mas o OpenCV tem funções para resolver isso, que pode encontrar o HSV para um valor BGR

```
green = np.uint8([[[0,255,0 ]]])
hsv_green = cv.cvtColor(green,cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
print( hsv_green ) # resulta em [[[ 60 255 255]]]
```

E para converter [HSV para BGR ou RGB](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d8/d01/group__imgproc__color__conversions.html#gga4e0972be5de079fed4e3a10e24ef5ef0a2a4b11ff7d29c342b66b85962a7969cd) (range de 0 a 180):

```
cv::COLOR_HSV2BGR = 54,
cv::COLOR_HSV2RGB = 55,
```

Ou (range de 0 a 255, provavelmente para questões de converter imagens esse vai ser o seu caso):

```
cv::COLOR_HSV2BGR_FULL = 70,
cv::COLOR_HSV2RGB_FULL = 71,
```

Então, sim o OpenCV pode trabalhar com RGB, além do BGR, depende de olhar a documentação, tanto para entender os padrões, quanto outras situações, e como dito na nota acima, softwares diferentes usam escalas diferentes.

Answer (score 0):

O formato de cor utilizado nos parâmetros `lowerb` e `upperb` é o HSV (Hue-Saturation-Value).

Assim como o Lucas Pedro comentou, e está escrito nessa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10951189/11679204) em inglês, o motivo dos valores **SV** ultrapassarem `100`, valor esse que teoricamente deveria ser o limite, é que diferentes aplicações podem usar diferentes escalas para o sistema de cor HSV.

Por exemplo, o GIMP utiliza para a **H** um valor de zero à 360 e para **S** e **V** um valor entre zero e 100. No caso do OpenCV, o *range* dos componentes da cor HSV são as seguintes:

```
H (matriz)     |  0 - 179
S (saturação)  |  0 - 255
V (brilho)     |  0 - 255
```

E sim, os *ranges* das cores da pergunta estão corretas. Para verificar isso, basta converter a cor HSV do OpenCV para a cor HSV normal, como no código abaixo:

```
blue_upper = [120, 255, 255]
int(360 / 179 * blue_upper[0]) # H: 241       HSV Normal: (241, 100, 100)
int(100 / 255 * blue_upper[1]) # S: 100%      RGB: (4, 0, 255)
int(100 / 255 * blue_upper[2]) # V: 100%      Hexadecimal: 0400FF
```